# Why does this function for Reference By Call not work

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, pass-by-reference, declaration

I am new to C and am currently learning about Pointers, more specifically about Reference By Call. I would like to ask why does this code work when I am trying to find the square of a number:

```
void sqrNum(int *x){

*x = *x * *x;

return;
 }
```

but this code does not work:

```
void sqrNum(int *x){

int temp, *y;

temp = *x;
*x = *y;
temp = (*y )* (*y);

return;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `*x = *y;` do, according to you? Because to me it seems like `y` is uninitialised, so accessing `*y` is accessing a random memory address. What do your compiler warnings have to say about it?

Comment: What's the point of `temp = *x;` if you reassign `temp` to `*y * *y` right after? Also, how can you check if any of these work? They don't return anything, so the whole body is useless for both.

Comment: In `sqrNum`, you forgot to define `y` before referencing it, which results in undefined behavior (don't ever do that, it's a severe bug).  Also, remove the empty `return` statements, all they do is clutter your code.

Comment: The simple answer is that it does not work because it is incorrect code, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out your misconceptions about pointers.

Comment: @Cheatah from what I assume it does. My initial though is that *y will have the value of *x. I'll check what my complier warnings say when I get back home! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I thought that temp will hold the value of *x. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah I see! Thank you for the help! Appreciate it! Oh the 'return' statement is not needed?

Comment: @IanAbbott I see! I am also unsure about my misconceptions about Pointers but I do get confused over when to see the 'dereference' operator.

Comment: The `return;` is not needed at the end of a function with return type `void`. The function will return implicitly when it reaches the closing brace. (That is bad for functions with return type other than `void` but perfectly fine for functions with return type `void`.)

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the incorrect work of the second function is very simple: you are using the uninitialized variable `y` in the assignment statement

```
*x = *y;
```

As a result the object pointed to by the pointer `x` will have an indeterminate value.

Variables with automatic storage duration (as the variable `y`) are not initialized implicitly and stay uninitialized if they are not initialized explicitly.

All other statements as for example

```
temp = *x;
```

and

```
temp = (*y )* (*y);
```

do not make a sense and do not influence on the object pointed to by the pointer `x`.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the help! I will take a deeper look as I need more time to understand it! Nonetheless, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

So with C-Pointers its often helpful to step through the operations step by step.

The first function you provided does the follow:

```
void sqrNum(int *x) {
```

This shows us the function takes a **pointer** to a bit of memory with an `int` in it (and that it returns nothing)

Next line is where the actual calculations happen:

```
*x = *x * *x;
```

This gets more readable when you use parenthesis (for example `*x = (*x) * (*x);`.

What it does is, set the piece of memory, pointed to by `x`, to be the value of `x` times `x`. Or in other words, the square.

This requires that `x` is actually **valid** and **initialized**.

---

Your second function also takes a pointer (`int* x`) and doesnt return anything (`void`).

You then start of by declaring to variables. One is a simple `int` the other one is a pointer `int *`.

```
int temp, *y;
```

To note here is, that these dont have any actual values yet. They just have been declared , **not initalized**.

Next then you assign `temp` the value stored in `x`.

```
temp = *x;
```

All good sofar.

Then you do **this**:

```
*x = *y;
```

Which tries to set the **value** stored in `x` to be the **value** stored in `y` *(the values stored in the memory piece pointed to by them)*.

This should set off a big warning sign in your head, because youre trying to access the value of `y`, which hasnt been initalized yet. This always leads to an error (or worse [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

You then try to do the same, right after with the line:

```
temp = (*y) * (*y)
```

Also to note here is, that you do not return any values or store the result in `x`, so nothing you actually stored after the function exits.

Additional, you can remove the `return` statements from the function, since theyre all of type `void`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This is really insightful and will be studying it further! Thank you for your help!

Comment: "the value of x" means the memory address, not the value stored in the memory location whose address it is. The text you have in the brackets should be the main text

Comment: @M.M Yes ofc thats true. I thought this would be comprehensible enough. Im gonna edit it quickly.

Comment: Alright, it makes a whole lot of sense already! Thank you for your help! I do have some questions though.

1) So instead of (*x) = (*x) * (*x); if I were to instead do (x) = (x) * (x), does that mean that it will be calculating the address instead of the value?

2) So based on what you said "Also to note here is, that you do not return any values or store the result in x, so nothing you actually stored after the function exits." I assume that in order to return a value, the variable that has to be used is the one that was declared in the formal argument?

Thanks for your help!